# Static routing in Ubuntu Server not quite working

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, routing, vagrant

So, I'm creating a virtual computer network using Vagrant with Ubuntu 14.04 boxes, based on topology shown here [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWp39.png).

And here is my Vagrantfile.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty32"
    config.vm.box_check_update = false
    config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', disabled: true

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.memory = "256"
    end

    config.vm.define "Router-1" do |r1|
        r1.vm.hostname = 'Router-1'

        r1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.1", netmask: "255.255.255.0", virtualbox__intnet: "c1r1net"
        r1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.1.1", netmask: "255.255.255.0", virtualbox__intnet: "r1r2net"
        r1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.2.1", netmask: "255.255.255.0", virtualbox__intnet: "r1r3net"

        r1.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
            vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", "Router-1"]
        end

        r1.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: <<-SHELL
            sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
            route add -net 192.168.3.0/24 gw 192.168.1.2 dev eth2
            route add -net 192.168.20.0/24 gw 192.168.1.2 dev eth2
        SHELL
    end

    config.vm.define "Router-2" do |r2|
        r2.vm.hostname = 'Router-2'

        r2.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.20.1", netmask: "255.255.255.0", virtualbox__intnet: "c2r2net"
        r2.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.1.2", netmask: "255.255.255.0", virtualbox__intnet: "r1r2net"
        r2.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.3.2", netmask: "255.255.255.0", virtualbox__intnet: "r2r3net"

        r2.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
            vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", "Router-2"]
        end

        r2.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: <<-SHELL
            sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
            route add -net 192.168.2.0/24 gw 192.168.1.1 dev eth2
            route add -net 192.168.10.0/24 gw 192.168.1.1 dev eth2
        SHELL
    end

    config.vm.define "Router-3" do |r3|
        r3.vm.hostname = 'Router-3'

        r3.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.2.3", netmask: "255.255.255.0", virtualbox__intnet: "r1r3net"
        r3.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.3.3", netmask: "255.255.255.0", virtualbox__intnet: "r2r3net"

        r3.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
            vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", "Router-3"]
        end

        r3.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: <<-SHELL
            sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
            route add -net 192.168.1.0/24 gw 192.168.2.1 dev eth1
            route add -net 192.168.10.0/24 gw 192.168.2.1 dev eth1
            route add -net 192.168.20.0/24 gw 192.168.3.2 dev eth2
        SHELL
    end

    config.vm.define "Client-1" do |c1|
        c1.vm.hostname = 'Client-1'

        c1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.2", netmask: "255.255.255.0", virtualbox__intnet: "c1r1net"

        c1.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
            vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", "Client-1"]
        end

        c1.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: <<-SHELL
            route add default gw 192.168.10.1 eth1
        SHELL
    end

    config.vm.define "Client-2" do |c2|
        c2.vm.hostname = 'Client-2'

        c2.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.20.2", netmask: "255.255.255.0", virtualbox__intnet: "c2r2net"

        c2.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
            vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", "Client-2"]
        end

        c2.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: <<-SHELL
            route add default gw 192.168.20.1 eth1
        SHELL
    end
end
```

For the most part, it's all good. The problem happens when I try to send ping message from `Client-1` to `192.168.3.3`, and also from `Client-2` to `192.168.2.3`, and vice versa. The ping message doesn't give success reply.

Am I missing something?

Comment: what say `traceroute` to destination? Can you ping from C1 to `192.168.2.3` and from C2 to `192.168.3.3`?

Comment: `traceroute` just gives me `no reply`. I can ping those addresses.

Comment: Probably C3 dont known where to route packet. Can you access to router C3 and run `tcpdump -i eth1 | grep 192.168.2.3`. Watch output while do ping from `Client1` to `192.168.2.3`. On this way you will see that the package cross throught interface `eth1`. Do `tcpdump -i eth2`, ping do still work. You will see that packet come or not to `eth2`. If come, then router dont known how to back them.

Comment: On `R1` you have route `route add -net 192.168.3.0/24 gw 192.168.1.2 dev eth2` Based on pickture gw must be `192.168.2.1`

Comment: @2707974 Did you mean the `gw` should be `192.168.2.3`? I've tried it, but then I can't connect to `192.168.3.2` anymore. I tell you, it's just so weird.

Comment: Hm. Packet from `R1` to `192.168.3.3` go to `R2` then to` R3` but `R3` have route to network `192.168.10.0/24` to go on `R1`. Try to change route on `R3` You must have only one path to network. Or you can add more precise route on `R1` to ip `192.168.3.3` something like `route add -net 192.168.3.3/32 gw 192.168.2.1 dev eth1` Then packet to network `192.168.3.0/24` will go to `R2` except for ip `192.168.3.3` When you ping `192.168.3.3` packet will go from `R1` directly to `R3`